# Convergent integral

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, improper-integrals, absolute-convergence, divergent-integrals

Find all the value of $\alpha >0$ such that $\int\limits_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x^\alpha +\sin x}dx$ converges.
My attempt is to check the convergence of $I_1= \int\limits_0^1 \dfrac{\sin x}{x^\alpha +\sin x}dx$ and $I_2=  \int\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x^\alpha +\sin x}dx$
It is easy to check $I_1$ converges $\forall\alpha >0$. What I concern here is when $I_2$ converges? Could someone help me to with $I_2$?

Comment: $I_2$ should converge for $\alpha > 1$. Note that you can bound it by $\frac{1}{x^\alpha + \sin x}$ and then let $x$ be large enough so that $x^\alpha + \sin x \approx x^\alpha$, which can be done since $\sin x$ is bounded above and below by 1. Then use the fact that $\int_1^\infty x^{-\alpha}dx$ converges for $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: This is one of those times you should not split the integral up at $1$ and instead choose another number like $2$ since you could potentially have an $x^\alpha - 1$ term in the denominator when you are trying to prove convergence and diveregence.

Comment: What about $\alpha\leq 1$? How can I prove in this case $I_2$ diverges?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can provide a stronger conclusion.
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}+\sin x}dx$$
is divergent when $0<\alpha\leq \frac{1}{2}$, conditionally convergent when $\frac{1}{2}<\alpha\leq1$, absolutely convergent when $\alpha>1$.

First, we note that $\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}+\sin x}$ is bounded near $x=0$, so it suffices to consider
$$\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}+\sin x}dx.$$

Then, we rewrite $\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}+\sin x}$ as
$$\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}+\sin x}=\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}-\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+\sin x)}.$$

It's easy to show that $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x^{\alpha}}dx$ is conditionally convergent when $0<\alpha\leq 1$, absolutely convergent when $\alpha>1$.
So we just need to consider $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+\sin x)}dx$.

When $0<\alpha\leq\frac{1}{2}$, we have
$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+\sin x)}\geq \frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)},$$
however $\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)}dx$ is divergent because

\begin{align*}
&\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)}dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos 2x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)}dx\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos 2x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)}dx
\\&\geq \frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{1}{2x^{2\alpha}}dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_1^{\infty}\frac{\cos 2x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+1)}dx,
\end{align*}

where the first term diverges and the sencond term converges.

When $\alpha>\frac{1}{2}$, we have

$$\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}+\sin x)}\leq\frac{1}{x^{\alpha}(x^{\alpha}-1)}\sim\frac{1}{x^{2\alpha}},$$
which is convergent.